# How to run Orange.canvas from within a python script and transform a Table to it?

Tags: python, orange

I'm new to Python & Orange, and want to make use of Spyder & Orange to do some data mining.
   I'm working with Rstudio & Rattle in this way:

...

```
# make a dataframe so called "mydata", then transform it to rattle
library(rattle)
rattle(dataset="mydata")
```

...

It's quite convenient to do some complex data preparation before calling Rattle, and then get the last script from Rattle. So I'm wondering about whether I can work in this way with Python or not.
   I find a script of running a Widget within a pyhton script like this:

```
import Orange
from Orange.widgets.visualize.owruleviewer import OWRuleViewer
from AnyQt.QtWidgets import QApplication
from Orange.classification import CN2Learner

data = Orange.data.Table("titanic")
learner = Orange.classification.CN2Learner()
model = learner(data)
model.instances = data

a = QApplication([])
ow = OWRuleViewer()
ow.set_classifier(model)

ow.show()
a.exec()
```

So, how to do with the Orange.canvas's main window?
Any idea is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I can run Orange within a python script:

...

```
# transform a pandas dataframe to an orange table
from Orange.data.pandas_compat import table_from_frame
ot1 = table_from_frame(data)
```

...

```
import sys
from Orange.canvas import __main__ as om
sys.exit(om.main(["-l 1","--no-splash","--no-welcome"]))
```

The question now is how to transform the orange table ot1 to orange, put it in a widget and place it in the canvas.

And I modify the source orangecanvas/main.py to work around the stdout & stderr problem, this bug is fixed in Python3.7.5:

...

```
def fix_win_pythonw_std_stream():
    """
    On windows when running without a console (using pythonw.exe without I/O
    redirection) the std[err|out] file descriptors are invalid
    (`http://bugs.python.org/issue706263`_). We `fix` this by setting the
    stdout/stderr to `os.devnull`.
    """
    if sys.platform == "win32" and \
            os.path.basename(sys.executable) == "pythonw.exe":
        # if sys.stdout is None or sys.stdout.fileno() < 0:
        #     sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, "w")
        # if sys.stderr is None or sys.stderr.fileno() < 0:
        #     sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, "w")

        # This bug is fixed in Python3.7.5
        print("win32 pythonw.exe")
```

...